# Can I use address space from one Internet Registry in the region of another?

Tags: networking, ip, internet

Is it possible for me to, for example, purchase address space from APNIC and then use those addresses in Europe or the United States? Would there be a cost or paperwork involved?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a question for both providers, not us. There's no technical reason why it would be impossible to do what you're asking for, but lots of 'political' and business type reasons why one or both of the providers might not want to play ball.

Answer (score 3):

From the [APNIC FAQ](http://www.apnic.net/services/services-apnic-provides/helpdesk/faqs/obtaining-resources---faqs#SeekIP):

> APNIC cannot guarantee that any address space it allocates will be globally routable. This is because the filtering policies implemented by transit providers around the world are beyond APNIC's control. The best way to avoid filtering problems is to ensure that your network is numbered into the address range of a larger network (such as your upstream ISP) so that many addresses can be aggregated and announced globally as a single route.

Basically, it's possible, but there's a risk some users won't be able to access the resources if they're located worldwide.

There's also the problem of requirements for [getting the IPs from APNIC in the first place](http://www.apnic.net/services/services-apnic-provides/helpdesk/faqs/obtaining-resources---faqs#CanBuy) but that's a different story.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is *yes*. Which registry you get your resources from is supposed to be based on where *you* are located, not where your equipment is located.